# Logic Problem in Vue App is Causing an Infinite Loop due to Co-dependent Variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am working on a vue app that can convert from fiat currency to crypto-currency and vise versa. A demo of the app can be found here: [Demo](https://quizzical-mayer-71f22d.netlify.com/#/).

You will note that the calculation is done and shown in the opposite input box automatically as text is entered. The issue is that currently the app just watches for changes in the variables bound to the inputs.

I also need this calculation to take place when the user chooses another selection from the selection box.

I have struggled thinking of a way to make this happen without causing an infinite loop.

Here was my naive attempt: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmPXvX?editors=1111).

Currently my understanding of why this does not work is because:

```
...input1 changes -> watch input1 called -> watch input1 modifies 
input2 -> watch input2 called -> watch input2 modifies input1....
```

Which is an infinite loop. There must be a part of Vue I'm not familiar with enough yet to handle this exact issue.

Thank you,

Comment: What's wrong with the previous `computed` solution?

Comment: The computed solution you offered me only watches for changes in the two input boxes. I need the calculation to be preformed also when there is a change in the select boxes. I was suggested to use watchers to do this.

Comment: If you also use the values from your `<select>` models in the computed properties, they will update when those change too. Presumably the selection should change the multiplier

Comment: I am using them in place of the const mul from your example but from my understanding the calculation is only preformed on the change of the input1 or input2 value.

`this.val2 = (val / this.cryptoRates[this.selectedCrypto][this.selectedFiat]).toFixed(3)`

My intuition is I'd need to set computed functions for both selectors like you have with the text boxes, but then how would I avoid writing to the global vars and causing an infinite loop?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The issue I guess is that the internal _values_ are only updated in the computed _setter_. If you could somehow change the logic to use the _getter_, you might have more luck

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@input` event listener. When you change the value in one input that changed will update the value of the other input.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="value1" @input="update2"> 
    to 
    <input v-model="value2" @input="update1">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const mul = 1.5;
export default {
  data: () => ({
    value1: null,
    value2: null
  }),
  methods: {
    update1() {
      this.value1 = this.value2 / mul;
    },
    update2() {
      this.value2 = this.value1 * mul;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You can make this work with `watch`, but then you'll need to prevent the update loop with an additional check:

```
watch: {
  value1(val) {
    const tmp = val * mul;
    if (tmp !== this.value2) {
      this.value2 = tmp;
    }
  },
  value2(val) {
    const tmp = val / mul;
    if (tmp !== this.value1) {
      this.value1 = tmp;
    }
  }
},
```

But this code assumes that multiplying by *x* and then dividing by *x* results in the exact same number, and while that mathematically true, with floats (javascript's number type) there are exceptions you'll need to guard against (NaN, rounding) that will make the code complex.

I therefor recommend the input event-listener approach.

Comment: It appears there is an issue with your solution, here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmPXvX?editors=1111) of it not working. I suppose if this did work i could use something like @change="update1" on my select boxes?

Comment: Looks like `@input` is not fireing in codepen, it does locally (with vue-cli) and yes add the @change event to the select.